# libgmp-10.dll missing error in Netbeans 7.1 for MinGW

Tags: ide, mingw, netbeans-7

I have installed C/C++ plugin in Netbeans 7.1 and configured MinGW.

[image]

But when I run the code, its showing libgmp-10.dll missing error. My IDE is even showing that its unable to find `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`.[ there were some underlined marks on the code]  (I have configured "C:\MinGW\bin" in system Path variable)

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("working")
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

this is the output I got.

```
    "/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/suryak/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/suryak/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
gcc.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.c
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/suryak/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/suryak/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 12s)
```

I still don't understand why this is happening.

I tried to add "make.exe" in the CMake option but it didn't even work.

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the MinGW install file, I downloaded a new version through the  netbeans site and it worked fine. [LINK](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html#mingw)

Actually, I found in the log file that MinGW couldn't download a file which caused error.